# Move files to a categorically numbered 'bucket' folders

Tags: batch-file

I have files with these names
1963.tif
1975.tif
2000.tif
2016.tif

in the folder name D:/Plans and I want to move these files into another folder that is categorized by date ranges such as

D:/Scans/1900 thru 1980  - A
D:/Scans/2000 thru 2020  - B

I want the first two .tif files to go to the A and the last 2 to go to B.
I found a script that will move files based on their starting number, but not on the ranges

```
@ECHO ON

SET Letters=(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z)
SET Numbers=(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
SET SourceDir=D:\Plans
SET DestNumDir=D:\Scans

FOR %%A IN %Letters% DO ECHO Y | MOVE "%SourceDir%\%%~A*.*" "%DestLetterDir%\%%~A\"
FOR %%B IN %Numbers% DO ECHO Y | MOVE "%SourceDir%\%%~B*.*" "%DestNumDir%\%%~B\"
GOTO EOF
```

Comment: this is a batch file not powershell

Comment: Change the tag to Batch

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Plans |
  ForEach-Object {
      If ([Int]$_.BaseName -le 1980) { Move-Item $_.FullName -Destination 'D:\1900s\' }
      If ([Int]$_.BaseName -ge 2000) { Move-Item $_.FullName -Destination 'D:\2000s\' }
  }
```

This should get you started on the direction you want, but your question isn't very clear.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$DirStar="C:\Temp\test"
$Before1980="C:\Temp\Scans\1900s"
$After1980="C:\Temp\Scans\2000s"

Get-ChildItem $DirStar -file -Filter "*.tif" | where basename -Match "^\d{4}$" | %{
  if ([int]$_.BaseName -le 1980)
  {
    move-item $_.FullName $Before1980
  }
  else
  {
    move-item $_.FullName $After1980
  }

}
```